# Win 10: Set an alarm that will auto-dismiss after 60 seconds of alarm sounding

Tags: windows-10, cortana, alarm-clock

With Cortana, a user can set up an alarm. In an office environment the alarm sounds forever and disturbs colleagues.

Is there a way to set a default auto-dismiss time for any future alarm made with Cortana?

Comment: You may try `Realarm` app. This is best alarm app on windows and supports voice commands as well.